Pushing onto tab stack in react navigation in Gorhom bottom sheet
In my react native application, I am using react navigation to handle my routing and gorhom's bottom sheet to handle bottom sheet interactions. This is how I currently have them setup.
NavigationWrapper.tsx
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { PLScreenRoute } from "navigation/screenRoutes";
import FeedTab from "navigation/tabs/feed/FeedTab";
import { BottomSheetModalProvider } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";

type NavigationWrapperProps = {
  setAppIsReady: () => void;
};

const NavigationWrapper = ({ setAppIsReady }: NavigationWrapperProps) => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
    >
      {/*modal provider is here so we can do routing inside of bottom sheets*/}
      <BottomSheetModalProvider>
        <Tab.Navigator
        >
          <Tab.Screen name={PLScreenRoute.FEED_ROOT} component={FeedTab} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </BottomSheetModalProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default NavigationWrapper;

And an example Tab
import { PLScreenRoute } from "navigation/screenRoutes";
import FeedScreen from "screens/feed/feed/FeedScreen";
import FeedHeader from "screens/feed/feed/FeedHeader";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

export const FeedTabStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const FeedTab = () => {
  return (
    <FeedTabStack.Navigator initialRouteName={PLScreenRoute.FEED}>
      <FeedTabStack.Screen
        name={PLScreenRoute.FEED}
        component={FeedScreen}
        options={{
          header: () => <FeedHeader />,
        }}
      />
    </FeedTabStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default FeedTab;

The issue I am running into is when I try and push a new route onto one of these tab stacks like such
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { PLScreenRoute } from "navigation/screenRoutes";

const navigator = useNavigation();
const navigate = () => navigator.push(PLScreenRoute.FEED)

If I do this outside of a bottom sheet, everything operates as expected. Once I do it within the bottom sheet is when my app crashes with the following error
TypeError: navigator.push is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
If I change to it navigator.navigate() then it works but I need the push() functionality, not navigate(). Since navigate() works but push() doesn't, this is why I believe the issue resides in the tab stacks.
Any thoughts?
